# Ubuntu Performance

Tags: google-chrome, performance, slowmovideo

I need to know about the performance of Ubuntu 18.because I couldn't get expected performance.

My Laptop Config:
4 GB Ram
Intel i3 processor
1 TB hard disk(60% free)

Right now I am using only

1. google chrome
2. VLC Player
3. Whats app desktop

I am getting hang suddenly or offlines videos getting buffer or the whole os get stuck until restart I can't do anything.

many time I thought to remove this OS but I heard Linux is best performance OS.someone help me to sort out the issue.

Comment: Paste the output of `sudo dmesg` command.

Comment: Do you have swap space defined? `free` will show you. You should have swap, at least 1.5xRAM size

Comment: You are 'only' running two potentially enormous resource hogs. Run the `top` command to see the biggest resource consumers. Run the `free` command to check if you have available memory. Sudden, unexpected freezes are often due to bad RAM - lookup how to run Memtest. Lookup how to run a SMART test to check you hard drive health.

Comment: You can always try different flavor from LiveCD/LiveUSB. I can recommend to try [Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/). You can also install MATE DE to the system with `apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop`.

Comment: thanks for your response. let me check these steps.

Comment: Hi, guys I have seen swap it is available. resource consuming max 15 % only.